# Getting 1120: Acess of undefined property resourceManager error

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am trying to change localization with that code down below :

```
resourceManager.localeChain = ["fr_FR"]
```

But i am getting undefined property error. I am new to Adobe-Air and Flex. I hope you help me to find out the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your application to support only one locale, you can set it as a style property, like so:

```
<fx:Style> 
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"; 
    s|Application { 
        locale: 'fr-FR'; 
    } 
</fx:Style>
```

If that doesn't work for you, you can read more about [Localization in Flex 4.5](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c-1c03f02c12bd00c4763-8000.html) here.